# How to list project based on a configuration from the SolutionFile class

Tags: msbuild, solution

How do you list all projects for a specific configuration from the SolutionFile class?

Comment: It's that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get my desired results:

(The snippet of code below was pulled from the ViewModel)

```
using Microsoft.Build.Construction;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

// Step #1 - Instantiate SolutionFile from a solution file name

    vm.SolutionFile = SolutionFile.Parse("SampleSolution.sln");

// Step #2 - Get List of Solution Configurations

    var list = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    foreach (var solutionConfiguration in vm.SolutionFile.SolutionConfigurations)
    {
        list.Add(solutionConfiguration.ConfigurationName + "|" + solutionConfiguration.PlatformName);
    }

    vm.SolutionConfigurations = list;

// Step #3 - Select the desired Configuration 

    vm.Configuration = [select a configuration from vm.SolutionConfigurations]

// Step #4 Get List of Projects based on Configuration

    var list = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    foreach (var project in vm.SolutionFile.ProjectsByGuid)
    {
        foreach (var projectConfiguration in project.Value.ProjectConfigurations)
        {
            if (vm.Configuration.Contains(projectConfiguration.Key.ToString()))
            {
                if (projectConfiguration.Value.IncludeInBuild)
                {
                    list.Add(project.Value.ProjectName);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    vm.ProjectsInConfiguration = list;
```

Comment: This was very useful.  The documentation for these APIs are garbage, and the trick that can be learned from this snippet is that the ProjectInSolution class' ProjectConfigurations is keyed by the _SOLUTION CONFIGURATION_, and the value is which project configuration is used by that solution configuration.  This is the necessary piece you'll likely not readily notice when looking at these APIs.  Thanks for this!